# Dynamic Survey with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to create a dynamic survery webpage with JavaScript.
I have 10 Questions which display types are set to "none" expect the first/actual questions displaytype is "block". Each question is a yes-no question. It's relevant which answer the user choose to see the next question.
I know how to build this static but I wanted a dynamic solution for this problem.
Can anybody help?
Here is a schema of my problem

[image: Survey schema]

Example code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>10 Questions</title>
  <script>
  ...
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <header>A Dynamic Questionaire.</header>
    <section>
      <article>
        <hgroup>
          <h1>Questionaire</h1>
          <h2>Anwer the questions in order as they appear.</h2>
        </hgroup>
        <div id="Question1" style="display:block;">
          1. 
          <button type="button" id="btnYes1">Yes</button>
          <button type="button" id="btnNo1">No</button>
        </div>
        <div id="Question2" style="display:none;">
          2. 
          <button type="button" id="btnYes2">Yes</button>
          <button type="button" id="btnNo2">No</button>
        </div>
        <div id="Question3" style="display:none;">
          3. 
          <button type="button" id="btnYes3">Yes</button>
          <button type="button" id="btnNo3">No</button>
        </div>
        <div id="Question4" style="display:none;">
          4. 
          <button type="button" id="btnYes4">Yes</button>
          <button type="button" id="btnNo4">No</button>
        </div>
        <div id="Question5" style="display:none;">
          5. 
          <button type="button" id="btnYes5">Yes</button>
          <button type="button" id="btnNo5">No</button>
        </div>
        <div id="Question5" style="display:none;">
          6. 
          <button type="button" id="btnYes6">Yes</button>
          <button type="button" id="btnNo6">No</button>
        </div>
        <div id="Question5" style="display:none;">
          7. 
          <button type="button" id="btnYes7">Yes</button>
          <button type="button" id="btnNo7">No</button>
        </div>
        <div id="Question5" style="display:none;">
          8. 
          <button type="button" id="btnYes8">Yes</button>
          <button type="button" id="btnNo8">No</button>
        </div>
        <div id="Question5" style="display:none;">
          9. 
          <button type="button" id="btnYes9">Yes</button>
          <button type="button" id="btnNo9">No</button>
        </div>
        <div id="Question5" style="display:none;">
          10. 
          <button type="button" id="btnYes10">Yes</button>
          <button type="button" id="btnNo10">No</button>
        </div>
      </article>
    </section>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why not use https://surveyjs.io/? You can dynamically build your survey using the framework.

Comment: I want to know how to create dynamic javascript by my own, but I don't know how to start cause I'm quiet not familiar to javascript.

Comment: Chances are nobody here will code it for you. You're supposed to code it yourself and come here when you have a specific problem (something doesn't work they way you expect and you can't figure out why).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a ton of ways you could do this. A quick approach would be to put some information in the button that indicates where to take the user next. So here I've added a `data-next` value on each button that matches the `id` of the next panel to show, and I toggle a class in CSS to show/hide panels.

```js
var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('button'),
  questions = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
  var button = buttons[i];
  button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var target = this.getAttribute('data-next');
    for (var j = 0; j < questions.length; j++) {
      var question = questions[j];
      if (question.id == target) {
        question.classList.add('show');
      } else if (question.classList.contains('show')) {
        question.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  });
}
```

```css
div {
  display: none;
}
.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="Question1" class="show">
  1.
  <button type="button" data-next="Question2">Yes</button>
  <button type="button" data-next="Question3">No</button>

</div>
<div id="Question2">
  2.
  <button type="button" data-next="Question4">Yes</button>
  <button type="button" data-next="Question5">No</button>
</div>
<div id="Question3">
  3.
  <button type="button" data-next="Question6">Yes</button>
  <button type="button" data-next="Question6">No</button>
</div>
<div id="Question4">
  4.
  <button type="button" data-next="Question10">Yes</button>
  <button type="button" data-next="Question10">No</button>
</div>
<div id="Question5">
  5.
  <button type="button" data-next="Question10">Yes</button>
  <button type="button" data-next="Question10">No</button>
</div>
<div id="Question6">
  6.
  <button type="button" data-next="Question7">Yes</button>
  <button type="button" data-next="Question8">No</button>
</div>
<div id="Question7">
  7.
  <button type="button" data-next="Question9">Yes</button>
  <button type="button" data-next="Question9">No</button>
</div>
<div id="Question8">
  8.
  <button type="button" data-next="Question9">Yes</button>
  <button type="button" data-next="Question9">No</button>
</div>
<div id="Question9">
  9.
  <button type="button" data-next="Question10">Yes</button>
  <button type="button" data-next="Question10">No</button>
</div>
<div id="Question10">
  10.
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks I know there are much ways but couldn't figure out that I can add such a property like data-next. And can manipulate the shown HTML via added CSS-Classes - I was doing this via setting the style.display Attribute.

Comment: @Ottospara no problem. In that case, I would recommend taking some beginner tutorials on javascript. There are plenty of free ones online. Welcome to Stack Overflow btw.